# Proving equivalence classes are disjoint or equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

I have the following problem:

Let R be a set with an equivalence relation ∼, prove that for all x, y ∈ X, either [x] = [y] or [x] ∩ [y] = ∅. (Here [x] denotes the equivalence class of an element x ∈ R).

I suppose that [x] ∩ [y] $\neq $ ∅, then there exists z $\in$[x]$\cap$[y], then zRx and zRy by definition ([x]={z$\in$R|z~x} and [y]= {z$\in$R|z~y}).

By symmetry we get xRz, with zRy and transitivity we get xRy.

So [x]$\subseteq$[y] and by symmetry we get [y]$\subseteq$[x] which implies that [x]=[y] else my assumption was false, and in that case [x] ∩ [y] = ∅.

Therefore, either [x] = [y] or [x] ∩ [y] = ∅.

Is this correct? I would appreciate any help and/or feedback.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes your reasoning is fine.